# I want to write a query to show totals on a single row for each provider

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data and I'd like to show my Remaining, Total and Utilised columns on a single row for each provider.

| Provider Name | Provider | Allocated | Remaining | Total | Utilised |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 a | p1 | 3801110 | 6857890 | 18142110 | 0.725684 |
| p1 b | p1 | 14341000 | 6857890 | 18142110 | 0.725684 |
| p2 a | p2 | 1946729 | 14935726.39 | 15064273.61 | 0.502142 |
| p2 b | p2 | 13117544.61 | 14935726.39 | 15064273.61 | 0.502142 |
| p4 a | p4 | 18415508 | 20236989 | 29763011 | 0.59526 |
| p4 a | p4 | 11347503 | 20236989 | 29763011 | 0.59526 |

Can you please help with me with a query which would give me the following result?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `ROW_NUMBER` and `CASE` expression?

Comment: Please edit your question and in stead of pictures show your data and expected result as text. Preferable in a way so we can easy create test data in our database. It would make it easy for us to search for a solution for you

Comment: Your results seem to pre-suppose an ordering -- the "first" row for each group has the values.  However, there is no obvious ordering.  How do you determine which row goes first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired results with something like the following. By only including an image of your data it's not possible to quickly test a solution so this is untested but hopefully gets you where you need to be.

```
    with t as (
        select ProviderName, Provider, Allocated, Remaining, Total, Utilised, 
          Row_Number() over (partition by provider order by ProviderName) rn
        from [table]
    )
    select ProviderName, Allocated,
        Iif(rn=1,Remaining,'') Remaining,
        Iif(rn=1,Total,'') Total,
        Iif(rn=1,Utilised,'') Utilised
    from t
    order by provider,rn
```

Comment: Thanks @sTTu. This works well. I just needed to add a cast to varchar as the values were numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should not do these things in the data layer. You should do these things in the UI layer.

You can still achieve this using LAG function.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(ProviderName varchar(10), [Provider] varchar(10),  
Allocated bigint    ,
Remaining   bigint,
Total   bigint, 
Utilised decimal(8,7)
)
insert into @table values
('p1 a',    'p1',   3801110,    6857890 ,18142110   ,0.725684),
('p1 b',        'p1',   14341000    ,6857890    ,18142110   ,0.725684);

SELECT providername, 
case when Allocated = lag(Allocated,1) over(partition by provider order by providername) then cast('' as varchar(20)) else cast(Allocated as varchar(20)) end as allocated,
case when remaining = lag(remaining,1) over(partition by provider order by providername) then cast('' as varchar(20)) else cast(remaining as varchar(20)) end as remaining,
case when total = lag(total,1) over(partition by provider order by providername) then cast('' as varchar(20)) else cast(total as varchar(20)) end as total,
case when utilised = lag(utilised,1) over(partition by provider order by providername) then cast('' as varchar(20)) else cast(utilised as varchar(20)) end as utilised

FROM @table
```

| providername | allocated | remaining | total | utilised |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 a | 3801110 | 6857890 | 18142110 | 0.7256840 |
| p1 b | 14341000 |  |  |  |